# Remove Subview not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift3, uiimageview

I have add a subview into an UIImageView and i try to remove the subview by calling the removeFromSuperview function but it is not working and the subview is still there...Any idea?

Below is my code:

```
 var path = CGMutablePath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 127.5, y: 13.5))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 165.0, y: 13.5))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 165.0, y: 51.5))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 127.5, y: 51.5))
        path.closeSubpath()

        var shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = path
        shape.opacity = 0.5
        shape.lineWidth = 3.0
        shape.fillColor = UIColor(hue: 0.786, saturation: 0.15, brightness: 0.89, alpha: 1.0).cgColor

        let pathClick = path.contains(location)

    if pathClick == true
            {
                let avgX = (127.5 + 127.5 + 165 + 165) / 4
                let avgY = (13.5 + 13.5 + 51.5 + 51.5) / 4
                let centerLocation = CGPoint(x: avgX, y: avgY)

                bubble.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 15, height: 15)
                bubble.center = centerLocation
                mapImageView.layer.addSublayer(shape)
                mapImageView.addSubview(bubble)
                handleMore()
            }
            else
            {
                bubble.removeFromSuperview()
                print("working")
            }
```

Comment: So if `pathClick` is true then you add the `buble` and if it´s false you remove something you haven´t added?

Comment: yup, if it is true the bubble will add and i want it to remove if it is false...i already try with the true scenario first then only try with the false one

Comment: But if `pathClick` is false then don´t do anything because you haven´t added it... Just remove the else statement or am I missing something here?

Comment: Could it be that you are adding the shape to mapImageView and bubble to mapImageView but are only removing bubble from its superview so shape remains

Comment: if i remove the else statement the bubble will not add as a subview

Comment: Is it the bubble view or the shape that is left there because you are never removing the shape.

Comment: ya i know the shape is not removing and i have put the removeFromSuperVIew for the shape and bubble but both is not removing

Comment: for layer: CALayer in mapImageView.layer.sublayers!
            {
                layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
            }
after my research i use this line but it always get crashed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only two solutions without the broad spectrum of the whole code.

1. You could just hide the `buble` and essentially it wouldn't be there at all.
2. `mapImageView` contains the subview of `buble`, maybe remove `buble`
   from `mapImageView`.

Answer (score 1):

it is not removing, because that is not view - you have added before. That is a another instance. You may access previous one from `mapImageView.subviews`, that is array of all subviews of your mapImageView. Identify which one is yours to remove, and use `identifiedView.removeFromSuperview`. You may use tags to identify your subviews. Another way is to remember your view when you are adding it as subview, and remove that view from superView. Anyway, you need to identify right subview.